# If I know the ID of a Chrome Web Store Extension, can I install via terminal?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I know the ID of an extension I want to install - `mdapmeleikeppmfgadilffngabfpibok` but I'd like to install with the command line.

Is this possible?

I'm wondering if I could use `wget` to download the file and then copy it to the chrome folder?

I can't see a built in command option on Chrome.

Comment: Are you sure the ID is correct? "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dmdapmeleikeppmfgadilffngabfpibok%26uc" errors out on me in Chromium. From what I found on the web it should download it  (and if it did commandline "wget" plus that should have  sufficed.